# select multiple insercion de varios datos a un solo campo

Tags: php, mysql

Mi pregunta es como poder guardar los datos de un `select multiple` a mi base de datos `mysql`; obviamente tiene mas datos eh probado con preguntas similares y nada soy novata en el tema `php`.

**HTML:**

```html
<label class="bmd-label-floating">Base Datos</label>
<br>
<select name="BaseDatos" id="BaseDatos" class="multiselect" multiple="">
  <option>ORACLE</option>
  <option>SQL</option>
  <option>MYSQL</option>
  <option>ORACLE 10G</option>
  <option>ORACLE 11G</option>
  <option>ORACLE 12G</option>
</select>
```

**INSERT:**

```
$BaseDatos=$_POST['BaseDatos'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO candidatos_llamados(BaseDatos)

VALUES ('$BaseDatos')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: Que errores te muestra?

Comment: bueno la verdad que solo me inserta la ultima opcion elegida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP devuelve un arreglo en el caso del select múltiple, lo mejor seria iterar sobre los elementos del arreglo para construir el INSERT múltiple, o también es posible usando la función implode de PHP que construye el String a partir de los elementos del arreglo de la siguiente forma:

```
$sql="INSERT ALL INTO candidatos_llamados (BaseDatos) VALUES ('";
$sql=$sql.implode("') INTO candidatos_llamados (BaseDatos) VALUES ('",$BaseDatos)."')";
```

de esta forma el sql se convierte en un (suponiendo que el arreglo tenga los valores 1,2,3 y 6):

```
INSERT ALL 
INTO candidatos_llamados (BaseDatos) VALUES ('1') 
INTO candidatos_llamados (BaseDatos) VALUES ('2') 
INTO candidatos_llamados (BaseDatos) VALUES ('3') 
INTO candidatos_llamados (BaseDatos) VALUES ('6')
```

Aceptado por Oracle para la inserción de los elementos.

Es importante tener en cuenta que el elemento del Select multiple en el HTML debe ser declarado como un arreglo:

```
<select multiple name="BaseDatos[]">
```

Comment: Bueno probare y te aviso

Comment: me marca error pero no me indica donde solo me muestra la pagina en blanco                                                                                                                    $BaseDatos=$_POST['BaseDatos'];

$sql="INSERT ALL INTO candidatos_llamados (BaseDatos) VALUES ('";
$sql=$sql.implode("') INTO candidatos_llamados (BaseDatos) VALUES ('",$BaseDatos)."')";   realize todo bien?

Comment: Creo que de acuerdo con su otro comentario lo que necesita es simplemente hacer el implode:

     $BaseDatos=$_POST['BaseDatos'];
     $bd=implode(',',$BaseDatos);
     $sql = "INSERT INTO candidatos_llamados(BaseDatos)
     VALUES ('$bd')";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);

Tenga en cuenta que en este caso los valores van a ser almacenados separados por coma, puede usar cualquier otro separador y luego cuando los vaya a leer puede usar la funcion explode que hace lo contrario, obtiene el arreglo a partir del texto usando el separador.

Comment: Buenas si me salio con la función implode $bd=implode(',',$BaseDatos); 
 ;Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Lo correcto sería recorrer `$BaseDatos` con un `foreach` y ejecutar el código sql por cada iteración.

```
  foreach($BaseDatos as $db){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO candidatos_llamados('campo')VALUES ('$db')";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: pero inserta los campos seleccionados en diferentes filas como que se realizo dos registros diferentes; lo que quiero es seleccionar por ejemplo dos datos y se inserten en ese solo campo BaseDatos