# Recoger todos los datos de un select multiple en laravel

Tags: laravel

Como puedo recoger los datos de un select multiple? Con el código que muestro a continuación solo me devuelve el último nombre de usuario que he elegido en el multiple select.

Form

```
 <form id="formGastos" method="POST" action ="{{route('gastosConduccion')}}">

<select style="WIDTH:100%;"  class="form-control select2" id="usuarios" 
  name="usuarios" multiple="multiple" >

     <option selected>Todos</option>

  @foreach($users as $user)

     <option >{{$user->name}}</option>

  @endforeach





</select>
</form>
```

Controller

```
 public function gastosConduccion(ConsultasRequest $request){


    $prueba = $request->usuarios;


     return $prueba;   


}
```

Ruta

```
Route::post('/consulta/gastos/conduccion', 'ConsultasController@gastosConduccion')->name('gastosConduccion');
```

Comment: No es clara tu pregunta ni lo que tratas de lograr, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Fijate en el nombre que le pones al select, Es importante tener en cuenta que el elemento del Select multiple en el HTML debe ser declarado como un arreglo https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/228463/92278

Comment: Ah vale no busque lo suficiente, y una vez hecho el arreglo como lo obtengo en el controller en laravel para poder usarlo, por que si pongo $prueba=$request->"usuarios[]"  eso me da error.

Comment: Y de la forma que lo tienes en la pregunta no te funciona?

Comment: En `$request->usuarios` vas a tener un array, pero no necesariamente con 5 elementos. Pero como te dicen en el primer comentario, no está claro lo que quieres lograr, el título está bueno, pero es difícil responder la pregunta... la respuesta corta sería "El nombre del Select multiple en el HTML debe ser declarado como un arreglo, y lo recoges así `$array = $request->usuarios;`"

Comment: muchisimas gracias con lo tuyo me sirvio a la perfección!:D

Answer (score 1):

simplemente al atributo `name` de tu select añade [] de esta forma

```
    <select style="WIDTH:100%;"  class="form-control select2" id="usuarios" 
  name="usuarios[]" multiple="multiple" >
```

de tal forma que cuando accedas mediante el `$request->usuarios` te va a llegar un array de lo que seleccionaste